# Slack Access token

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api

As a Developer,I need to send the notification to the user's Slack Channel (That channel has Jenkins CI app)  from Jenkins dynamically.

So I have to get the below things of Jenkins CI app(Already installed in user's channel)by using Slack OAuth.

```
1.Team Subdomain 
2.Integration Token
3.Base URL
```

I got the access token by using Slack API Documentation. But I don't have the clue to get those things by using access token in API Call. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to sent messages into a channel, you can simply use the incoming webhook that has already been installed for Jenkins.

Just take the existing URL and make a HTTP POST request to that URL like this:

```
POST https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-type: application/json
{
    "text": "Hello, world."
}
```

The correct channel should already be pre-configured, but you can also specify your own by adding the `channel` property to your request.

See the [official documentation](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) on more details on how to use incoming webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through each one:

1. Team Subdomain. Each Slack Workspace looks something like this: `https://<teamname>.slack.com` where  is used to access the Slack Workspace. So in order to access the workspace you need to know what it's subdomain is or in this case the `<teamname>`
2. The integration token and base url can be found in the webhook url from Jenkins. Your URL should look something like this: `https://example.com/hooks/xxxx`. Where xxx is the Integration token and `https://example.com/` is the base url

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you said the incoming webhook response, https://example.com/hooks/xxxx.Where xxx is the Integration token. But, I want to get the Jenkins CI app response. Can you please tell another way to get Jenkins CI app integration token.
Note: I checked to match the xxx and Jenkins integration token. But It's not same.